# xkill equivalent for Windows

Tags: windows

Is there a reliable equivalent of xkill for Windows?

For those who don't know what xkill is: it is a Unix tool which basically kills the process of any windows you click on.

A Windows port can be downloaded [here](http://solo-dev.deviantart.com/art/Windows-xKill-100737525).

Comment: It would be helpful for those unfamiliar with xkill if you gave a brief description of that it's doing.

Comment: I came across [this windows port of xkill](https://bitbucket.org/sta-ger/win-xkill). I've only just tried it, but it seems to do exactly what it's supposed to do just fine. [It's available via chocolatey as well](https://chocolatey.org/packages/win-xkill): `choco install win-xkill`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Windows [xkill](http://www.ghacks.net/2008/10/18/windows-xkill/).

Disclaimer:
I got it from google and I haven't tried it.

**Update**: Process Explorer has a [window Finder function](http://rfvicente.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!5228FAA8B79B6EB1!348.entry). Very useful to locate a window.

Comment: this link is outdated, see http://superuser.com/a/230900/76871 after downloading the sysinternals microsoft utility

Comment: As of Process Explorer 17.02, I could find it only on the toolbar as an icon but not using a menu.

Answer (score 7):

[PSKILL](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896683.aspx) from the [SysInternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/0e18b180-9b7a-4c49-8120-c47c5a693683.aspx) suite is very handy.   [PSLIST](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896682.aspx) and [PSINFO](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897550.aspx) are related tools.   You can view the entire Sysinternals Live tools directory in a browser at http://live.sysinternals.com. , or download a ZIP file from [here](http://download.sysinternals.com/Files/SysinternalsSuite.zip).

To kill process based on its window, install [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) (from the Sysinternals). It got the option to find window's process by dragging over the window.

Answer (score 7):

```
taskkill /im ProcessName.exe /f
```

The "f" is for "force".

Answer (score 1):

There is [WinKill](https://casey.io/winkill/). Does exactly that and it's free. Rightckick -> Kill to get rid of hidden processes too.

Comment: been a while. the link is dead.

Comment: That app disables the Win key, it doesn't allow you to kill an application; whoever updated the link didn't put in the correct one.